# Sufficient condition for convergence in distribution in the plane

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm trying to show convergence in distribution for a sequence $X_n$ of random variables in the plane. Here's what I know.  I have a sort of squeeze theorem for the probability of the r.v.s being in a rectangle of diameter $\epsilon$.  I have

$$
 f_n(\epsilon,x,y) \leq \mathbb{P}\big(X_n \in (x, x+\epsilon)\times(y,y+\epsilon)\big) \leq g_n(\epsilon,x,y),
$$
where 
$$
f_n(\epsilon,x,y) \underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} F(x,y) (1-o(\epsilon)) h(\epsilon),
$$
$$
g_n(\epsilon,x,y) \underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} F(x,y) h(\epsilon),
$$
and where $h$ is $o(\epsilon)$ and $F$ is continuous.

I know more about these functions of course, I'm just trying to make the problem as abstract as possible so as to not bog readers down in the specifics of my model.

I want to conclude that I have weak convergence of $X_n$ to a r.v. with density $F(x,y)$.  Is this possible with what I have?  What else would I need?

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Is no one answering cause it's ill-formed?  Too abstract?  Too hard?  Should I ask on mathoverflow?  My last question had no answers either, so I'd love an idea of what I'm doing wrong on this site.